# Mail server not picked up by TLS diagnostic tools

Tags: email-server, tls

I have mailing server under mail.luken-tech.pl .
Can anyone explain how this:
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=mail.luken-tech.pl&hideResults=on shows "Assessment failed: Unable to connect to server", this: http://www.checktls.com/perl/TestReceiver.pl gives me "Cannot connect to server (reason: Connection refused)".

But this:

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect mail.luken-tech.pl:587 -tls1 -ign_eof
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect mail.luken-tech.pl:587 -tls1_1 -ign_eof
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect mail.luken-tech.pl:587 -tls1_2 -ign_eof
```

Works perfectly fine, and my server generally seems to work ok? :) Why any testing tool cannot connect to my smtp? It bothers me because I configured one server before, and I didn't have something like that. Should I care about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone explain how this: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=mail.luken-tech.pl&hideResults=on shows "**Assessment failed: Unable to connect to server**"

SSLLabs only [support HTTPS Testing](https://community.qualys.com/thread/12348). Your mail server speak with STARTTLS  and SMTP protocol. The [error message](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=mail.luken-tech.pl%3A587) confirm the limitation

```
Ports other than 443 not supported
```

> This http://www.checktls.com/perl/TestReceiver.pl gives me "**Cannot connect to server (reason: Connection refused)**"

This test will send email to your host via default port i.e. port 25, not port 587 as you intended. Apparently, port 25 on your server is closed

```
$ telnet mail.luken-tech.pl 25
Trying 91.196.50.126...
telnet: connect to address 91.196.50.126: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

If you want test, you can use your mail client (for example thunderbird), native openssl (you have done it) or [swaks](http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/latest/doc/ref.txt)